# Retrieve the manual format clipboard

Tags: centos, man, clipboard

I'd like to retrieve the manual to the clipboard, usually implement the following steps:

```
# man crontab
# man crontab > draft.md
# cat draft.md
```

then copy it manually from the console,
How could I get it done in a straight forward way?

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: centos @nohillside

Comment: Don't work as root (if `#` is a root prompt). Reading a manual does not require root privileges.

Comment: Where do you want to paste it? [According to comments, you are not running a GUI](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/461718/retrieve-the-manual-format-clipboard#comment840016_461729), so it would be interesting to know what you mean by clipboard and what you are attempting to do with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `xclip`:

```
man crontab | xclip -i
```

This will copy the content of the crontab manpage to the clipboard.

Note: copy&paste is only possible in a graphical environment, not on a text-only console (unless using `screen` or `tmux`, or inside a text editor).

Comment: Error: Can't open display: (null) centos-release-7-5.1804.el7.centos.2.x86_64

Comment: Are you using a X graphical environment (KDE, GNOME, ...)?

Comment: I am not sure, I am learning on the server, a remote cloud server running Centos

Comment: Do you see windows, icons, the mouse pointer? Or only text?

Comment: no, just the cursor.

Comment: So you are on a text-only console.